# How to animate a button getting clicked inside a forEach loop?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I am trying to animate the button when user taps on it. It offsets on the side making it look like it's pressed.

If you look at the images you should see why I want to animate it by offsetting it since I have a background behind the button which is offset and the button should match that frame when clicked.

Currently the button animates as shown in the picture when tapped but all of the button animates getting pressed and they don't return to original position after the click happens.

Button before clicked
[image: Button before clicked]

Button after click
[image: Button after click]

Below is the buttons array:

```
@State private var isClicked = false
    
    
    let buttons: [[CalcButton]] = [
        [.clear, .plusMinus, .percent, .divide],
        [.seven, .eight, .nine, .multiply],
        [.four, .five, .six, .minus],
        [.one, .two, .three, .add],
        [.zero, .doubleZero, .decimal, .equals]
    ]
```

```swift
ForEach(buttons, id: \.self) { row in
    HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(row, id: \.self) { item in
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.animation()
                }
            } , label: {
                ZStack {

                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: buttonWidth(button: item), height: buttonHeight())
                        .foregroundColor(.backgroundColor)
                        .offset(x: 7.0, y: 7.0)

                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: buttonWidth(button: item), height: buttonHeight())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)


                    Text(item.rawValue)
                        .font(.custom("ChicagoFLF", size: 27))
                        .frame(width: buttonWidth(button: item), height: buttonHeight())
                        .foregroundColor(.backgroundColor)
                        .border(Color.backgroundColor, width: 4)
                        .offset(x: isClicked ? 7 : 0, y: isClicked ? 7 : 0)

                }

            })

        }
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 10)

}
```

This is the function to toggle the isClicked state variable

```swift
func animation() {
    self.isClicked.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Try calling `self.isClicked.toggle()` twice. That's not the best solution but It looks like you're toggling to `isClicked = true` but never back to `isClicked = false`

Comment: Include all of your code.

Comment: @mahan Added the buttons array. Let me know what else is missing. I think that's all of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a selection state for each button. so better to create a custom button.

Here is the demo version code.

Custom Button view

```
struct CustomButton: View {
    var text: String
    var action: () -> Void
    
    @State private var isPressed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // Do something..
        }, label: {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .offset(x: 7.0, y: 7.0)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Text(text)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                    .offset(x: isPressed ? 7 : 0, y: isPressed ? 7 : 0)
            }
            
        })
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged({ _ in
                    // Comment this line if you want stay effect after clicked
                    isPressed = true
                })
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    isPressed = false
                    // // Uncomment below line and comment above line if you want stay effect after clicked
                    //isPressed.toggle()
                    action()
                })
        )
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                CustomButton(text: index.description) {
                    print("Action")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to keep your effect after clicked. Just replace this code part.

```
.simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged({ _ in
                })
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    isPressed.toggle()
                    action()
                })
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to make the opacity stay the same regardless of button is pressed?

Comment: Try to remove button and keep the only zstack

Comment: Hi, is there a way to contact you? We have an app on the AppStore - a highly praised app by people from all over the world and wanted to chat with you.. maybe check your facebook dms